# Java Socket with Amazon AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the Elastic Load Balancer in front of a Web Server. There will be a applet running in the background of an EC2 machine.

Let's say if the EC2 machine public IP is 50.1.1.1 also the inbound firewall is configured for port 1024 to allow all connections, then I can create an applet at the client machine, and create a socket:

```
Socket newSocket = new Socket(50.1.1.1,1024);
```

The above will connect successfully, however, if I replace the 50.1.1.1 with the Elastic Load Balancer DNS, it will not connect (HTTP Bad Request), even though it is a healthy elastic load balancer instance with configuration TCP port 1024 for health checks.

Is there something wrong with how I interpret ELB? (A front end connection before the web server)?

Thanks

Comment: You are right. Traffic to the DNS of the load balancer will hit your EC2 instances behind it. The point of an ELB is to balance traffic load across whichever pool size of EC2 instances you have available, hence 'elastic'. It doesn't make sense to try to have the ELB in front of a pool of size one (single EC2 instance) like you are trying. If you have just a single instance, there's nothing to balance across. I'm not even sure if you can have an ELB in front of a single instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want to make sure that one instances work, if not, then there is a problem. That's why I wanted to use just 1 instance at the moment.

Comment: @quicksort yes, you can have an ELB with just one instance behind it.

Comment: EBLs certainly offer more than load balancing; SSL termination and extended monitoring for example.